# Matlab : Counting image in a folder using matlab GUI

Tags: matlab

I want to count the number of image in a folder using a GUI created in Matlab guide 2015b. 
I have written this code:

```
Id = 3 (actually the value of id will be given by user at          run time)
path =strcat ( ' c:\user\Desktop\New\TrainData\',Id)
path=strcat  (path,'\')
d=dir (path)
n=length (d)
```

It shows the error that `dir` can not be used for cell input. This code is working when I use command prompt.
It shows error only when I want to use it through GUI. Initially I thought that it's a problem regarding the path.
So I displayed the path but it gave the perfect result.
I am confused. Kindly provide some solutions in Matlab

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `strcat` you should use `fullfile`:

```
path = fullfile('c:\user\Desktop\New\TrainData',num2str(Id))
```

And be careful with dir, dir also list the subfolder so check that you only take into account the image file:

```
d    = dir(path);
name = d(~[d.isdir]).name
```

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're getting your `Id` variable from a `inputdlg` or something. It is being read in as a *cell array of strings* rather than a string. You can check this using `iscell`:

```
iscell(Id)
%   1
```

You don't see any issues until you hit the `dir` command because `strcat` is able to handle this just fine but *also* yields a cell array of strings.

```
out = strcat('123', {'4'});
class(out)
%   cell
```

If you read your error message thoroughly, the error explicitly states that the input to `dir` is a cell and not a string. The way to fix this is to first check if `Id` is a cell array and convert to a string if necessary.

```
Id = inputdlg('Enter an ID');

% Convert to a string if Id is a cell array
if iscell(Id)
    Id = Id{1};
end

% Get a listing of all files/directories
d = dir(fullfile(folder, num2str(I)));

% Get number of files
nFiles = sum(~[d.isdir]);
```

Also, you don't want to try to concatenate a number with a string (`strcat('abc', 1)`) because this will convert the number to it's ASCII code. Instead you'll want to use `num2str` as shown above.

Comment: When would the `'String'` property of an `'edit'` `uicontrol` return a cell array?

Comment: @excaza Well it *can* hold a cell array but you're right, I was actually thinking of `inputdlg`. I'll update.